# Docker-compose extend not finding environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have part of a docker-compose file as so

#### docker-compose.yml

```
  pitchjob-fpm01:
    container_name: pitchjob-fpm01     
    env_file: 
      - env/base.env 
    build:
      context: ./pitch
      dockerfile: PitchjobDockerfile
    volumes:
      - "/Sites/pitch/pitchjob/:/Sites"
    restart: always 
    depends_on:
      - memcached01
      - memcached02      
    links: 
      - memcached01
      - memcached02
    extends:
      file: "shared/common.yml"
      service: pitch-common-env
```

my extended yml file is

#### compose.yml

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  pitch-common-env:
    environment:
      APP_VOL_DIR: Sites
      WEB_ROOT_FOLDER: web
      CONFIG_FOLDER: app/config
      APP_NAME: sony_pitch
```

in the docker file for pitchjob-fpm01 i have a command like so

#### PitchjobDockerfile

```
# Set folder groups
RUN chown -Rf www-data:www-data /$APP_VOL_DIR
```

But when I run the command to bring up the stack

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-base.yml up --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

I get the following error

> failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chown -Rf www-data:www-data
> /$APP_VOL_DIR' returned a non-zero code: 1

I'm guessing this is because it doesn't have the $APP_VOL_DIR, but why is that so if the docker compose is extending another compose file that defines
environment: variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [build-time arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) for that.

In *Dockerfile* define:

```
ARG APP_VOL_DIR=app_vol_dir
# Set folder groups
RUN chown -Rf www-data:www-data /$APP_VOL_DIR
```

Then in *docker-compose.yml* set app_vol_dir as build argument:

```
pitchjob-fpm01:
  container_name: pitchjob-fpm01     
  env_file: 
    - env/base.env 
  build:
    context: ./pitch
    dockerfile: PitchjobDockerfile
    args:
      - app_vol_dir=Sites
```

Comment: are build time args overridden by subsequent compose files?

Comment: yes they are. If you are extending some compose file, you can override previous args

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not with the overrides, but with the way you are trying to do environment variable substitution. From the docs:

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, RUN [ "echo", "$HOME" ]will not do variable substitution
>   on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use theshell form
>   or execute a shell directly, for example:RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo
>   $HOME" ].

Comment: so could i from the common.yml build another container with just ENV statements in that are included?

Comment: my problem being i have 5 apps and a dockerfile for each 4 of them extend a base webserver dockerfile and the 5th extends something else but i need them ENV vars in all 5 of the containers, and would like to keep it as DRY as possible